# How do I generate a preset amount of random numbers?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program that generates a set amount of numbers (user input), and then saves the output to file.

Problem is I don't know how to set the amount of times to generate said number. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to take input from a user, or how to write a loop?

Comment: The way my program works is that the user inputs the amount of random numbers to be generated. I'm trying to figure out how to take that number, and make it so that my program generates that set amount then saves it to a .txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t fully understand your question but for random numbers generation you can use Random class like:

```
int numberOfElems = int.Parse(userImput.Text);
Ramdom r = new Random();
List<int> myNumbers = new List<int>();
for(int i=0; i<numberOfElems; ++i)
{
   int number = r.Next(0,100); // will bring a random number from 0 to 99
   myNumbers.Add(number);
}
```

This will generate the amount of numbers you requested.

Comment: Well [here](http://pastebin.com/yXqzBQWi) is my code currently. Now VS Studio keeps saying "System.IO.{"The process cannot access the file 'd:\\file.txt' because it is being used by another process."}".

Comment: you provably opened the file in another moment and did not close it. As a good practice, you can access files via `using (StreamReader strd) { ....}` so the stream will be closed at the end.

Comment: Not sure I follow. To clarify this should write the amount of numbers specified (line by line) then save? I'm not sure why VS won't write the file. I checked, and it made an empty text with the name, but no data.

Comment: open another question about how to store a List<int> into a file, will be the clearest way to proceed.

Comment: I'll research it more on Google. Stackoverflow hates new programmers apparently. Just look at the score of my question.

Comment: is not about the level of the problem to solve is about the way you exposed it and the amount of information you provided. BTW, take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rnd2 = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < yourLimit; i++) {
    int myRand = rnd2.Next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough:

```
var count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var random = new Random();
var numbers = new List<int>();
for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    numbers.Add(random.Next(0, 1000));
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\output.txt", numbers.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```